# A proof question involving a regular set and a context free language

Tags: automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Claim: Let $L \subseteq \Sigma^*\{\#\}\Sigma^*$ be a context-free language, where $\# \notin \Sigma$. Suppose that for each $x \in \Sigma^*$, $\{y|x\#y \in L\}$ is finite. Then $\{y|\text{ for some } x\in \Sigma^*, x\#y \in L\}$ is a regular set.

I need to prove the above claim.

Since for each $x \in \Sigma^*$, $\{y|x\#y \in L\}$ is a finite set by assumption, we see that $\{y|\text{ for some } x\in \Sigma^*, x\#y \in L\}$ is also a finite set. Since every finite set is regular, $\{y|\text{ for some } x\in \Sigma^*, x\#y \in L\}$ is a regular set. Can this be a valid proof?

Comment: Thank you for the below correction! I am still trying to prove the above claim. For each $x \in \Sigma^*$, let $L_x=\{y|x\#y \in L\}$. Then, $L_x$ is a regular set since it is finite.  Is $B=\{y|\text{ for some } x\in \Sigma^*, x\#y \in L\}$ the union of (possibly infinite) $L_x$, $x \in \Sigma^*$? Since the union of a regular set is regular, $B$ is regular. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument has a flaw. Consider for instance the language $L = \{a^n\#b^n \mid n \geqslant0\}$. Then, for each $x \in \Sigma^*$, there is at most one $y$ such that $x\#y \in L$. However, 
$$
\{y \in \Sigma^* \mid x\#y \in L \text{ for some }x \in \Sigma^*\} = \{b^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}.
$$ 
Indeed, if $y = b^n$, there exists some $x \in \Sigma^*$ (namely $x = a^n$) such that $x\#y \in L$.